# In vim, how to scroll horizontally, by just one character, when cursor reaches end of the window?

Tags: vim

Instead, vim scrolls the view by one full page, making it very difficult to follow a long line of code.

Line wrapping is of course disabled, and we want to just use the arrow keys and not `zl`.

Is there a vim option for configuring in .vimrc the desired behavior?

Comment: I believe you, but am somewhat surprised as GOOG takes their coding style guide pretty seriously. Got a filename?

Comment: I could have mistaken it to be Google's code (it could've been redistributed open source code). Anyway, the file is Python-2.7.4/Lib/urllib.py, line 489. It can be downloaded from http://googleappengine.googlecode.com/files/google_appengine_1.7.7.zip

Comment: Yep, that's in the base Python distribution but that module has been deprecated in 3.x so is unlikely to change. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate, but I can't see a link to the question it's a duplicate *of*.

Comment: While this is marked as a duplicate the question referenced is about moving quickly and the answers do not answer this question. This question is pretty much the opposite question: how does one move more _slowly_? The accepted answer here is perfect for this question and not a desirable answer on the referenced "duplicate."

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You're looking for

```
:set sidescroll=1
```

(or any other small number). The default is `0`, which scrolls by half a screen. See also `sidescrolloff` for how near the cursor must come to the border to trigger scrolling.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I couldn't systematically find it in vim's help files using just **horizontal** and **scroll** as keywords.

Comment: another +1 for the sensei's very thoughtful `sidescrolloff` tip if I also could.